# How can I fix error of compilation in my app?

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I had added dependency and then I have deleted one.

It' s now existing error of complication:

```
find symbol class PhotoDraweeView
```

```
  public final PhotoDraweeView photo;
               ^
  symbol:   class PhotoDraweeView
  location: class FragmentGalleryBinding
```

I've tried to clean cache and rebuild app. Also I 've tried to invalidate caches.  But it's not successfully.